# I cant use Bootstrap "form-control" when using MaterializeCSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, materialize

When I use MaterializeCSS, I can't use the `form-control` class of Bootstrap.

How can I solve this problem?

```
<div class="card card-panel col-lg-12 form-group" style="float:right;direction:rtl;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><input class="form-control" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

It show me this:

[image]

but I need this:

[image]

Comment: Can you use a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/new#) to show what you are dealing with? I am not able to reproduce the original error

Comment: not show me error .  it use the materiallize input , but i need the bootstrap input in project

Comment: Have you tried to put the bootstrap file below your materialize file?